# access php array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have 4 divs and on mouseover of each, I want the `src` of an `img` to change.
I have to get the images from **PHP**.
How can I use the array that I get in **PHP** over in my jQquery script?
And I know with just 4, I could just set up the array in javascript and put each image name, but that's not the functionality I'm looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
div{
height:100px;
width:100px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:blue;  
}
#my_image{
height:100px;
width:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

</style>

<?php

$images = scandir("images", 1);

?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(div).mouseover(function(){
        $("#my_image").attr("src", /*my php array*/);
    });

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <img id="my_image" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the final result to be. A single image can only have one SRC.

Comment: I want the src to change to a different image based on which div the mouse is over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var images = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;
```

Then you have an array called `images` that you can use in your JavaScript code. Using it at the position of your comment makes no sense though. You can't assign an array to the src of an image.

Comment: right, it would be like this: $("#my_image").attr("src", images[0]);